# Magento is duplicating images

Tags: product-images

I noticed that Magento stores some images at the following path /media/catalog/product/A/C, however it is duplicating the images many times. For example:

AC41412_Black_1.jpg
AC41412_Black_2.jpg
AC41412_Black_3.jpg
AC41412_Black_4.jpg
AC41412_Black_5.jpg
AC41412_Black_6.jpg
AC41412_Black_7.jpg
AC41412_Black_8.jpg
AC41412_Black_9.jpg
AC41412_Black_10.jpg
AC41412_Black_11.jpg
AC41412_Black_12.jpg
AC41412_Black_13.jpg
AC41412_Black_14.jpg
AC41412_Black_15.jpg

Can anyone tell me the reason why Magento does this as it's taking up a lot of disk space.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When it is happening?

Answer (score 1):

When you upload image to the product, Magento will not check if the file name is exist or not, but Magento will save a new image, if the file name is exist then magento will rename the file to be like this {filename}_1, {filename}_2,{filename}_3.
anyway there are a lot of script that will clean the images that is not used by Magento

see this free extension for **magento 1**

https://www.magecloud.net/marketplace/extension/image-clean/

and this free extension for **magento 2**

https://magecomp.com/magento-2-image-clean.html

Hope this will help you